# Input js validation & storing inputed user data in cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

If name is entered, `newsletter` class will disappear and `newsletter1` class will appear displaying `Thankyou for joining, [Nameofuser]`

I have a form to input name and email. When the email is entered in correct format, popup appears `Successful` and I am trying to save that name in cookie. So when I refresh the page, it will display `Thankyou for joining, [Nameofuser]`

This is what I have achieved so far: I am not able to save the input name in cookies

http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FAEWXAJJ7VKX

https://jsfiddle.net/sachitmaskey/kav5y1ba/

**CSS**

```
<head>
    <style>
        .newsletter {
            margin - bottom: 33 px;
        }

        .newsletter1 {
            z - index: 99999;
            margin - top: -250 px;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

**HTML**

```
<body onload = "checkCookie()">
    <div class="newsletter" style="float: left;">
        <h3>NEWSLETTER</h3>

        Name :<input type="text" name="name"><br>

        <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
            Email: <input type="text" name="email">
            <br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
            <p id="demo"></p>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div class="newsletter1" style="float: left;">
        <p id="thankyou">  
        </p><br>
    </div>
</body>

</html>



**JAVASCRIPT**
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
        var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
        var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
            alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
            return false;
        } else {

            alert("Successful");
            // If name is entered,newsletter class will disapper and newsletter1 class will appear displaying "Thankyou"


            if (y > 0) {

                $('.newsletter1').css('display', 'block');
                $('.newsletter').css('display', 'none');


                // setting cookie, getting cookie and checking cookie if it exist or not
                function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
                    var d = new Date();
                    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
                    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
                }

                function getCookie(cname) {
                    var name = cname + "=";
                    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                        var c = ca[i];
                        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                            c = c.substring(1);
                        }
                        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                        }
                    }
                    return "";
                }

                function checkCookie() {
                    var user = getCookie("name");
                    if (user != "") {
                        setCookie("name", user, 30);
                        document.getElementById("thankyou").innerHTML = "Thankyou for joining...."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit outdated to use cookies and I would use window.localStorage instead.

Much simpler:

```
localStorage.setItem('name', "John Smith");
console.log(localStorage.getItem('name')); // "John Smith"

localStorage.removeItem('name');
console.log(localStorage.getItem('name')); // null
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better for you to use cache instead of cookies because there might be some possibilities that the session is made expired by your server which meant every time user visits the page is handled by new session and the old session is destroyed. I recommend you to use browser cache instead.